# Get complement of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have the following array and a list of indices

```
my_array = np.array([ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8] ])
indices = np.array([0,2])
```

I can get the values of the array corresponding to my indices by just doing `my_array[indices]`, which gives me the expected result

```
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

Now I want to get the complement of it. As mentioned in one of the answers, doing

```
my_array[~indices]
```

Will not give the expected result `[[3,4],[7,8]]`.

I was hoping this could be done in a 1-liner way, without having to define additional masks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html). It returns a new array with sub-arrays along an axis deleted.

```
complement = np.delete(my_array, indices, axis=0)
```

```
>>> np.delete(my_array, indices, axis=0)
array([[3, 4],
       [7, 8]])
```

Comment: Could you explain why the intuitive `~` returns unexpected result?

Comment: Why on earth would `~` (bitwise inverse) give the expected result?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis A simple reason is that `arr.shape == (~arr).shape`, which is clearly not what we need here.

Comment: Thank you Riccardo for answering in a kind and explicative way!